# Scala - schedule a task at a given time of the day: run a task everyday at 6pm

Tags: scala, email, task, scheduler, schedule

my questions is how i schedule a task to be executed every day at a given time.

I have the next code:

```
class ScheduleService {
   private val mail = new MailController

   def sendMailSchedule={

     val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
     val scheduler = actorSystem.scheduler
     val task = new Runnable { 
      def run() { 
        mail.sendMail("user@gmail.com", "Subject", "Body")
        println("Send")} 
      }
     implicit val executor = actorSystem.dispatcher

     scheduler.schedule(
       initialDelay = 0 seconds,
       interval = 7 day,
       runnable = task)
  }
}
```

Mail Controller is implemented and it send mails.

This code sends a mail every 7 days. What i want is to send a mail at 6 pm everyday.

Comment: How about using a [Crontab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab)?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, you have an initial delay of zero seconds. If you calculate the distance in time between now, and the next instance of 6pm, then use that as an initial delay, with a standard delay of 1 day, you will get what you want.

For example if right now it is 4:45pm, you want an initial delay of 75 minutes.

```
scheduler.schedule(
   initialDelay = timeToNext6pm,
   interval = 1 day,
   runnable = task)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "with a standard delay of 1 day, you will get what you want"?

I get the part about the initialDelay i will try to implement it, but do you mean to set the interval to 1 day? (interval: 1 day)?

After setting up the initialDelay how i say it to be every day?

Comment: Just make sure you don't hardcode `timeToNext6pm`, but calculate it at runtime.

Comment: Thanks! it worked :D ye i calculate the time with Calendar.getInstance.getTime.

Comment: You may consider DST and TimeZone, it may move one hour ahead and early depending on GST if you go by exactly fixed intervals.